# Firestore listener mechanism efficiency

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

If I understand correctly, in the initialization phase of `addSnapshotListener` you get a list of all the documents (even if it is 500 trillion documents) from the QuerySnapshot if you call the `getDocuments` function.
Then, every time you modify or add a document to a collection, you get from `QuerySnapshot` all the documents that have been modified by calling the `getDocumentChanges` function or all the existing documents by calling `getDocuments`.

That means both at the initialization stage and after every change, I always get a list of all the documents. That's logical? Assuming I have 500 trillion documents under the same collection (just for the sake of exaggeration), at every change and initialization of the app will I get them all?

Is that really the case?
Or is it some kind of lazy instantiation or something?
Because if so, when I would like to question the whole collection, no matter what I get at first the whole list?

Answer (score 0):

The `QuerySnapshot` always contains all documents that match the query (or collection reference). Even when there's an update and only a subset of the documents matched by the query is changed, the `QuerySnapshot` still contains all of the documents, even though in its communication between the SDK and the backend serves, Firestore only synchronizes the modified documents. If you only want to process the changes, you can [process just the changes between the snapshots](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#view_changes_between_snapshots).

Comment: The question is what about the bandwidth that the information needs to go through. Even if we assume that I only process the changed document (say only 1 that was added), in any case all the existing documents in the collection are sent to me from the server, which means that even if I do not process them, billions of documents will still be read and sent at a time. If there are trillions of documents in the collection, does that mean that every little change will send tens or hundreds of megabytes at a time? @Frank van Puffelen

Comment: "in its communication between the SDK and the backend serves, Firestore only synchronizes the modified documents"

Comment: So the price only considers those that have changed?  If for example there are a trillion documents, but only 10 of them have been updated and trigger the listener, in terms of price would that count as reading 10 documents or a trillion?  And what about a case where every time a new query is created (say there is no optimization and a user logs off and connects to the app intermittently) or I decide to create a new query every time, will each time the first reading count as a trillion readings even though nothing has changed?

Comment: Correct: if you have an active listener and there are changes to some of the documents it listens to, only those modified documents are sent from the server to the client.